# XLForm formValidationErrors for fields with no title displays "(null)"

Tags: ios, validation, xlform

Right now, for rows without title, "(null)" will be used in the alert for `formValidationErrors`

Is there a way to
1. hide the `title` of the row if I set it? OR
2. Make the alert search for the `placeholder` when `title` is absent?

It does make sense to use the `placeholder` in place of the `title`, since the rows look nicer using placeholders rather than titles.

Any help or suggestion is greatly appreciated! =D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can override -(XLFormValidationStatus *) doValidation  in XLFormRowDescriptor 
   and set message to returned XLFormValidationStatus;
2. You can override -(NSArray *)formValidationErrors in XLFormViewController, first NSError description returned is displayed.
3. You can override -(void)showFormValidationError:(NSError *)error in XLFormViewController and display UIAlertView on your own.

I do not use it yet (considering currently) but this is how I see it from source code...

Comment: I'm just gonna accept it first since I have already moved on from this. I decided not to do any validation at all, and to leave all validations to my web server

Answer (score 2):

Set `row.requireMsg` to the text you would like to be displayed in the alert for `formValidationErrors`

Answer (score 0):

i think you can do these steps

Go To your XLForm.m file where your define rows and colums.

See where you don't give the title to row if you don't want to give title just assign this line not empty.

```
  row = [XLFormRowDescriptor formRowDescriptorWithTag:@"nil)" rowType:XLFormRowDescriptorTypeText title:@""];
```

i think that is helpful.